# How to Exclude Empty String in Countifs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have an excel sheet with 2000+ rows and 15 columns. I need to count the entries in a certain column based on conditions of other columns. Here's a sample of the sheet:

```
  A    |     B    |    C    |   D   |     E
-------------------------------------------------
Fruit  |  Origin  |  Price  |  Qty  |  Feedback
-------------------------------------------------
Apple  |  Amazon  |   100   |   4   |    Great
Banana |  India   |   100   |   1   |
Orange |  Africa  |   200   |   2   |    Good
Apple  |  Amazon  |   300   |   5   |
Guava  |  India   |   100   |   1   |    Great
Banana |  India   |   400   |   5   |
Orange |  India   |   200   |   6   |
Apple  |  Amazon  |   100   |   8   |    Good
Kiwi   |  Africa  |   300   |   5   |
Banana |  Africa  |   500   |   4   |
Apple  |  Amazon  |   100   |   1   |    Good
Orange |  Amazon  |   300   |   5   |
Kiwi   |  India   |   200   |   4   |
Guava  |  India   |   100   |   1   |    Good
Apple  |  Amazon  |   300   |   5   |    Good
Banana |  Africa  |   100   |   4   |
Apple  |  Amazon  |   200   |   1   |    Great
Guava  |  India   |   200   |   5   |
Orange |  Amazon  |   300   |   1   |    Good
Apple  |  Amazon  |   200   |   5   |    Good
```

Now I need to get the number of feedbacks for Apple Fruit with Origin as Amazon, Price greater than 100 and quantity greater than 2. So my formula would go as:

`=COUNTIFS(A:A, "Apple", B:B, "Amazon", C:C, ">100", D:D, ">2")`

Now I want to add another condition to get the feedbacks which are filled (not empty), so my formula would go like:

`=COUNTIFS(A:A, "Apple", B:B, "Amazon", C:C, ">100", D:D, ">2", E:E, "<>")`

Ideally, the above formula would yield a result of `3`. Now if the blank cells in Column `E` are empty strings `""`, then the above formula returns `4`, as the formula treats `""` the same as filled value. Can anyone suggest a formula in which I would exclude the empty strings `""` in my COUNTIF condition, so that my result comes as `3` even with the empty strings in Column `E`?

Appreciate the help in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A100="Apple")*(B2:B100="Amazon")*(C2:C100>100)*(D2:D100>2)*(E2:E100<>""))
```

`SUMPRODUCT()` supports a very intuitive way to test for empties.

[image]

Where the only valid are row 16 and row 21.

**EDIT#1:**

Here are references:

[Exceljet](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function)

Comment: This formula solved my problem, but I still didn't get what SUMPRODUCT does exactly?

Answer (score 4):

Nice little question and indeed an anoying issue. `COUNTIFS()` does support wildcards. A "?" stands for any single character whereas the "*" stands for any 0+ characters. Therefor combining those two wildcards into "?*" we are telling the function to test if the cell holds *at least a single character* (possibly more). Funny enough a zero-width string `=""` is not triggered by this because, as by definition (and suggested by it's name) they are indeed **zero**-width strings.

I think with your sample data you'd want to return "2", right? Anyways, try:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Apple",B:B,"Amazon",C:C,">100",D:D,">2",E:E,"?*")
```

[image]

Comment: @MujeeburRahman. That's very strange. As per the screenshot you can see it worked a treat for me.

Comment: I asked the question for a particular data in my organization, but I cannot share it anywhere. So I created my own example data to clearly explain the scenario. Though the formula you suggested worked on this example data, it didn't work on the data which I'm working on in my org. The above marked answer (SUMPRODUCT) worked fine.

Comment: Anyways, thanks for your answer. It might be helpful in some scenarios, but I never used it or came across them.